# Break part of a string in php

Tags: php

```
Data: https://www.ccc.com/admin/index.php?route=channel/cok&token=e49fb985ce93c7eb8adfc01cdf91617b?shop_id=25881721
```

**Above data that return from URL, how can I break it and store into variable like example below:**

```
$raw = https://www.ccc.com/admin/index.php?route=channel/cok&token=e49fb985ce93c7eb8adfc01cdf91617b

$value = 25881721
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether this help or not.

```html
<?php
$a= " https://www.ccc.com/admin/index.php?route=channel/cok&token=e49fb985ce93c7eb8adfc01cdf91617b?shop_id=25881721";
$b=explode("?shop_id=",$a);
$raw=$b[0];
$value=$b[1];
print_r('raw='.$raw);
echo "<br>";
print_r('value='.$value);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I think your URL is malformed:

```
https://www.ccc.com/admin/index.php?route=channel/cok&token=e49fb985ce93c7eb8adfc01cdf91617b?shop_id=25881721
```

You shouldn't be able to have two question marks. But let's assume that second question mark is a type, there is a function for parsing URLs: [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

For example:

```
$url = '//www.example.com/path?googleguy=googley';
var_dump(parse_url($url));
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["host"]=>
  string(15) "www.example.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(5) "/path"
  ["query"]=>
  string(17) "googleguy=googley"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP explode() function.

Give a try with below code

```
$raw = "https://www.ccc.com/admin/index.php?route=channel/cok&token=e49fb985ce93c7eb8adfc01cdf91617b?shop_id=25881721";

$result = explode('?shop_id=',$raw);

echo $url= $result[0]; //https://www.ccc.com/admin/index.php?route=channel/cok&token=e49fb985ce93c7eb8adfc01cdf91617b

echo $parameter= $result[1];  //25881721
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it using [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) predefined php functions.

```
$formattedUrl = parse_url($url);
parse_str($formattedUrl['query'], $query);
echo $query['shop_id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with explode function

```
$data = "Data: https://www.ccc.com/admin/index.php?route=channel/cok&token=e49fb985ce93c7eb8adfc01cdf91617b?shop_id=25881721";
$raw = explode("Data: ", $data)[1];
echo "Raw: $raw";
$value = explode("?shop_id=", $data)[1];
echo " Value: $value";
```